# How to avoid "505: HTTP Version not supported" error?

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, bing-api, http-status-code-505

I am trying to use the Bing SOAP API for a simple search request. But now that I finally figured out how to send the request using JAX-WS, I am stuck again. I get the reply 
`com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.ClientTransportException: The server sent HTTP status code 505: HTTP Version not supported` when I send the request. Can anyone help me out?

I am using dynamic invocation with JAX-WS 2.0, if that makes any difference.

```
Dispatch<SOAPMessage> dispatch = service.createDispatch(
    portName, SOAPMessage.class, Service.Mode.MESSAGE);
MessageFactory messageFactory = ((SOAPBinding) dispatch.getBinding())
    .getMessageFactory();
SOAPMessage request = messageFactory.createMessage();
// Add content to the request
SOAPMessage response = dispatch.invoke(request);
```

Wireshark tells me, that the request header contains `POST /soap.asmx HTTP/1.1` and the reply comes back also with an HTTP/1.1 versioning. Doesn't this mean, it's alright?

Thanks, moxn

**UPDATE**:
It's not a JAX-WS specific error. I implemented the communication via Commons HTTPClient and still get the same 505.

Following the headers from the HTTPClient request:

```
Content-Length: 435
Content-Type: text/xml
Host: api.bing.net:80
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.0.1 (java 1.5)
Expect: 100-Continue
```

**UPDATE**: 
It also doesn't work with HTTP/1.0 btw...

Comment: Can you show the full request you are trying to send (URL and the complete post from your Wireshark capture)? Sometimes space in a URL or post can cause this issue. i.e. the error might be pointing a different problem than what you think it is..

Comment: @gbvb Hey, thanks for inquiring. I completely forgot about this question. I already got it figured out (see answer below).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the meantime I got my answer in the Bing developer forum. It seems as if Microsoft is sort of using different semantics for HTTP response codes than most and a 505 can also mean **"Something is wrong with your SOAP request"**. Turns out I did not use the correct namespaces. After fixing them, the request went through just fine.

Here is the [link to the thread](http://www.bing.com/community/developer/f/12254/p/661425/9628329.aspx) in the Bing forum.

Comment: Nice job figuring that one out.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried adding the following to app.config or web.config?

```
<configuration>
  <system.net>
    <settings>
      <servicePointManager expect100Continue="false" />
    </settings>
  </system.net>
</configuration>
```

Obviously sending the `Expect: 100-continue` in request header causes the “505: HTTP Version not supported” error to be thrown.

[image: Expect 100-continue]